# Angular testing: Why is there no race condition involved in while mocking HTTP calls in the given example?

Tags: angular, angular-test

Consider the following short test case mentioned [here](https://testing-angular.com/testing-services/#testing-services):

```
describe('FlickrService', () => {
  let flickrService: FlickrService;
  let controller: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [FlickrService],
    });
    flickrService = TestBed.inject(FlickrService);
    controller = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('searches for public photos', () => {
    let actualPhotos: Photo[] | undefined;
    flickrService.searchPublicPhotos(searchTerm).subscribe(
      (otherPhotos) => {
        actualPhotos = otherPhotos;
      }
    );

    const request = controller.expectOne(expectedUrl);
    request.flush({ photos: { photo: photos } });
    controller.verify();

    expect(actualPhotos).toEqual(photos);
  });
});
```

My question is how can we guarantee that the expectation `expect(actualPhotos).toEqual(photos)` would run before the observable `flickrService.searchPublicPhotos`'s *next* method is called. Won't there be a race condition, and shouldn't we be using `tick()` before making the *assert* call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how `searchPublicPhotos` is implemented. If it is emitting right away (like with `of()`) it will work but if it's asynchronous (like a http call or even a `delay(0)`) your subscribe will trigger after your expect check. Since you probably don't want to rely on the implementation that much it is not advised to use it like this. Instead you can use jest's done call back for testing asynchronous code:

```
it('searches for public photos', done => {
    flickrService.searchPublicPhotos(searchTerm).subscribe(actualPhotos => {
        expect(actualPhotos).toEqual(photos);
        done();
    });

    const request = controller.expectOne(expectedUrl);
    request.flush({ photos: { photo: photos } });
    controller.verify();
});
```

If done() isn't called the test will fail.

Comment: True, but I want to know if the example I gave from the webpage, is a correct test case or whether there'll be any race condition associated with it. Basically, I want to know if that example is correct and if so, why is it correct

Comment: Ah :) It depends on how searchPublicPhotos is implemented. If it is emitting right away (like with `of()`) it will work but if it's asynchronous (like a http call or even a `delay(0)`) your subscribe will trigger after your expect check. Since you probably don't want to rely on the implementation that much it's much safer to use the done callback anyways.

Comment: Kindly update the answer with this information so that I can mark it as accepted